# Deleting or refreshing a treeview in Tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, treeview

I am writing a small program that takes input from a SQLite DB and prints out information in the GUI, based on the selection from a Combobox. Basically it's trading information from the game Freelancer (which goods are sold at a specific base). I got it to work so far as that it prints out the first selection in a Treeview. However, when I want to print the next (different) selection, it does not refresh but creates a new Treeview bellow the first. I tried several things including a destroy() but I can't get it to work. Below is the code I wrote. I edited a bit with some fixed data instead of pulling from the SQLite DB.
The 'Bases' button populates the combobox.
The 'Goods sold at base' button takes the combobox's selection and produces the treeview.

```
from Tkinter import *
import csv, sqlite3, sys
from ttk import Combobox, Treeview

root = Tk()
root.minsize(width=500, height=300)

v = StringVar() # ========= v is a variable that stores the selection(s) from the combobox ============
dropdownBases = []
goodsSoldAtBase = []
tree_header = []

def on_field_change(index, value, op):
    v = boxBases.get()
    print 'v is', v

def List_bases():
    data = ['base1', 'base2', 'base3', 'base4',]
    for i in data:
        dropdownBases.append(i)
    boxBases.config(values=dropdownBases)

def List_sold_at_base():

    destroy_widget()

    sb=v.get()
    print sb
    dataFromDB = [['base1', 'Cobalt 275', 'Copper 180'],['base2', 'High Temp Alloy 280', 'Mining Machinery 130'],
    ['base3', 'H-Fuel 240', 'Oxygen 6', 'Water 18'], ['base4', 'Hydrocarbons 40', 'Polymers 107']]
    for i in dataFromDB:
        if i[0] == sb:
            goodsSoldAtBase.append(i[1])
            goodsSoldAtBase.append(i[2])
    # --------------- print for control purpose-------------------
        print i
    print "\n", dataFromDB
    print "\n", goodsSoldAtBase
    tree_header = ["Commodity Name", "Price"]
    #================== build the treeview and populate it =============================
    container = Frame(printLabel)
    container.pack(side= TOP, fill='both', expand=True)

    # create a treeview with scrollbar
    tree = Treeview(columns=tree_header, show="headings")
    vsb = Scrollbar(orient="vertical", command=tree.yview)

    tree.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='nsew', in_=container)
    vsb.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky='ns', in_=container)
    container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

    for col in tree_header:
        tree.heading(col, text=col.title())

    for item in goodsSoldAtBase:
        tree.insert('', 'end', values=item)
        # adjust column's width if necessary to fit each value

def destroy_widget():
    try:
        container.destroy()
    except:
        pass

def selection(event):
    v=boxBases.current()

def file_menu():

    root.title("Freelancer trade helper")
    menubar = Menu(root)
    root.config(menu=menubar)

    fileMenu = Menu(menubar)
    fileMenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=quit)
    menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=fileMenu)

# ================== Frames ===========================

leftFrame= Frame(root)
leftFrame.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH)

rightFrame= Frame(root)
rightFrame.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=BOTH, expand=TRUE)

printLabel = Label(rightFrame, relief=SUNKEN)
printLabel .pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=BOTH, expand=TRUE)



# ================== Buttons ==========================

boxBases = Combobox(rightFrame, textvar=v, values=dropdownBases)
boxBases.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', selection)
boxBases.pack(side=TOP, anchor=NW, fill=X)

baseButton=Button(leftFrame, text="Bases", command=List_bases)
baseButton.pack(side=TOP, anchor=W, fill=X)

goodsButton = Button(leftFrame, text="Goods sold at base", command=List_sold_at_base)
goodsButton.pack(side=TOP)

file_menu()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than destroying and re-making the entire widget, why don't you clear the old data out and put the new data in the same same widget?

Comment: That would work as well. I tried clearing it but didn't find a good way for it. I'm not sure how I would replace it since now it just makes a new Treeview bellow the first one. I figured I need to desroy or forget it, but re-making it would be better. Could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: [A quick google search shows many results](https://www.google.com/search?q=tkinter+Treeview+clear) for that. It's hard to give more help since you did not provide a complete example that I can work with and test.

Comment: I'm having a hard time figuring this out. The code above works in so far as that it shows the issue I'm having. If you press the 'Base' button and make a selection in the Combobox , then press the "Goods..." button, it makes a Treeview. If you do this again, it just makes a new one bellow the first one instead of replacing it. If I try to delete() or forget() the frame 'container' it errors on it being referenced outside the funtion. Try: / Except: statements at the beginning of the function won't work for me. It feels like I'm missing something....